# Hosted Custom Fonts on HTML Email Signature

Tags: html-email

Before I begin, I'm a designer, not a coder.
I've successfully created an HTML signature with custom hosted fonts using @font-face, however, once I send the email and receive a reply, the font formatting is lost. It defaults back to Arial or whatever.

here's my code, am I doing something wrong? 
I've listed the font family name as `sfd'. I can't remember if this is the actual name, or if it's just an alias I created.

```
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
    @media screen {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'sfd';
        src: url('http://archive.friendthemagazine.com/email_signature/studiofrontdesk-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('http://archive.friendthemagazine.com/email_signature/studiofrontdesk-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    }

    * {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Not every client even bothers to read `<style>` tags. Some ignore them. Some actively strip them out. You may want to test with a tool like [Litmus](https://litmus.com) when designing.

Comment: Did the below answer work for you?

Answer (score 3):

You are not doing anything wrong. The font you are using (*studiofrontdesk-regular-webfont*) is a web fonts, there are only a handful of devices that read/render web fonts. Below is a list for you.

- Apple Mail
- Outlook for Mac
- iOS

[Source](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts/): List updated 20th September 2021

Only these email clients will show the web fonts and the rest will read the fall back font. Add the fallback fonts (Arial etc) to your font family.

One method I use for my emails is to have the web font and the below code specifically for Outlook.

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <style>
        table, table td{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 'sans-serif' !important;}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

When emails are replied, the fonts that are on the users system or default to Outlook are used.

Comment: The clients are also under zero obligation to preserve the formatting in any replies.

Comment: Where is the list of email clients from?

Comment: The list can be found on Litmus or Email on Acid. I have updated the list with a source.

Answer (score -1):

Your font is not a downloaded font. So once you send it, it is indeed gone. What you could try is downloading the font, place the file inside the directory you are in now. And put the name of the downloaded font inside your source.

**Like this:**

```
@font-face { 
font-family: fontname; 
src: url('fontname.otf'); 
}
```

Hope this helped!